# JQuery Accordion overwrite styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with JQuery Accordion...

[Details Here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)

My problem is that I need to overwrite some of it's styles to apply my design.

Has anyone got information on this?

Comment: Load your custom CSS file, which overrides CSS styles by CSS class, after jQuery UIs own theme CSS file

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you're after a CSS change, not a javascript change. Whilst you could use JS if you wanted.

$('selector').css(something);

This would add inline styles which would override the currents styles. I would suggest looking at something like this:

Original Styles

```
.jamie {
     position: fixed;
}
```

new styles in separate new style sheet:

```
div.jamie {
     position: fixed;
}
```

Don't forget style sheets are cascading ;)